# how to make proper async request inside cypress.on(test:after:run,...)

Tags: cypress

I am facing an issue with cleanup action after test run, What I need to do is after each test run, I need to call a certain API to store the result , here's my simplified code,

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test) => {
  Cypress.log({
    name: 'Reporting..',
    message: 'Sending Test result..',
  })
  ...
    add_result(test..) //async request
  ...
  Cypress.log({
    name: 'Reporting..',
    message: 'Test Result Send Succesfully',
  })
})
```

And this works for most of the test, but it doesnt work for the last test run of spec file, i am assuming it is because the browser is closed after the last test run but i am not sure, What can i do here?

Comment: Please add the error messages you are getting while executing the code. It will provide better clarity and helps in easier debugging.

Comment: There is no error code, the 'test:after:run' method never executes or the async request in it doesn't complete, since the browser close automatically as soon as the test completes.
The test works fine when I pass 'cypress run --no-exit' but the problem is this will leave the browser open and have to cleanup manually later on.

Comment: Any news here. ? I have exactly the same problem